# Sump Pump Float Setting

Tags: sump

My submersible sump runs several times an hour nearly year round. It is backed by a municipal water driven pump. During a recent power outage I noticed the water level stabilized at 1/4” above the the bottom of the upper inlet pipe. Does anything need to be adjusted or am I unnecessarily drawing water & pumping the entire subdivision?

Comment: "Stabilized" **with** or **without** the backup-water-powered-pump operating? They are generally easy to adjust, so you could just try changing it while keeping an eye out for water intrusion.

Comment: Can try raising the float adjustment higher a couple of inches, don't want it to be too high.  This should slow down when the pump comes on.  You are probably on a high water table, and might be a good idea to get a battery backup pump.

Comment: @crip659 , FYI a battery pump would be a silly waste of $ when they have a municipal backed pump those battery pumps don’t last long when was the last time that the power was out & municipal water system was down long enough for the tank to go dry? I haven’t seen that happen but I have seen many battery backed pumps fail, mostly because the batteries are not replaced but even with new batteries they only last for a short time.

Comment: @EdBeal  You are right.  I blame my limited knowledge of water powered pumps, and did not realize OPs other pump did not require power.

Answer (score 0):

How far below the slab is the upper inlet pipe?
This info is needed for a proper answer, here is mine.

If the upper inlet is at least 6-8” below your floor I would set your pump at that upper level, why 6-8 or more,, well the slab will be 4-6 plus some compacted rock (in my area) 2+” so if the inlet pipe is far enough below the slab and rock that it won’t wick water.  set it at that level because it should not cause problems and watch the humidity level or moisture on the slab with the plastic taped down test.
If you find the humidity increases or moisture in the slab is wicking up the extra cost of pumping to a lower level is worth it.

If nothing changes except your power bill is lower enjoy the savings.  But be aware if all of your neighbors and you do this and there is a large rain fall event it may be enough to overwhelm the pumping systems. So make any changes with caution.